# How to ensure android device is always connected to wifi regardless of its state?

Tags: adb, wi-fi, internet, developer-options

Is there any developer setting option or `adb` command that forces android devices to always maintain their wifi connection even if the device is idle or locked? Sometimes my devices don't respond to connection requests and that has been a headache.

Comment: Is Wi-Fi -> Advanced -> Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep enabled, already?